# How to prevent apathy and corner cutting when nothing happens so people feel secure?

Tags: management

Say that you have a software team that is supposed to aggressively check for code quality and bugs and security errors. Eventually you get to the point where people don't find anything so they start to slack off. Lots of code is sent through with maybe 2-3 minutes of review now. People do not expect to find anything so they do not bother to check.

This kind of thing happens in many industries. Plenty of regulators just pass things through without really checking all that much. I did when I worked for the TSA screening luggage.

How do you prevent this?

Comment: What're the consequences for a bug or security error slipping through?

Comment: And related to Erik's comment: _are_ bugs and security errors slipping through? If not, don't worry about it because the informal processes are working.

Answer (score 8):

Isn't it obvious? You test them from time to time by submitting code that contains known issues (don't be too clumsy creating these). Then you build statistics on how many of these are missed and act on these statistics (by additional training, bonuses, reprimands, etc.).

I'd find it disappointing if TSA didn't do something similar. But you can find so many horror stories about that organization online that it wouldn't be exactly surprising.

It might be useful to you to read about Stack Overflow's ["review audits"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/157121/what-are-review-tests-audits-and-how-do-they-work).

Comment: The TSA DOES do secret performance tests. The results are generally not public but often leaked. No wonder, their failure rate in detecting obvious weapons is between 80% and 95% (See https://onemileatatime.com/tsa-failure-rate/ ) The test by itself doesn't fix the problem..

Comment: @Hilmar No, it doesn't fix the issue (although even knowing that such tests happen could mitigate some of it). As I mention, you need to act on the test results.

Comment: But that's the question: what should that action be? Punitive, retraining, process-change, motivational, incentives ?

Answer (score 1):

US secret service agents apparently only [work three to five years in a protective assignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Secret_Service#:%7E:text=After%20their%20field%20office%20experience,for%20three%20to%20five%20years.), after that they will be assigned other duties and new agents take over their jobs. Maybe a similar rotation scheme will also work in other industries where people performing a particular function should not be feeling too secure but hungry, attentive and actively looking for dangers/bugs.

Comment: I don't find a proof of statement in the given link. Where can I see that: a) secret agents really work only 3-5 years b) that it's an effective strategy c) which problems it solves.

Answer (score 0):

**Code Quality**:

Enforce use of standards for code quality at merge. Python has PEP-8 for example, most IDEs will issue warnings on code duplication etc. Just google your stack for such programs and enforce the use of them. I.E: you don't get to merge if this tool raises warnings.

**Bugs**

This one is a toughie. Normally code review should weed out the biggest ones.
Unit tests before merge should find more of them. Look into TDD if you really want to go down this rabbit hole, but be aware that any kind of CI/CD unit testing automation comes with its own overhead and challenges.

QA helping out the devs by testing code on unmerged dev branches could also help.

Also the previous approach of "don't merge until no warnings/bugs" can also be used.
In the case of TDD your metric should be a green suite but be aware of metrics as people will make a green board an objective instead of quality code with no bugs.

**Security errors**

Depending on what your stack is, you could use tools like SonarQube as a required step before merge. They give out really detailed reports and are highly customisable.
Again, this is dependant on your stack so you might need to look for alternatives.

Comment: Style guides like PEP8 are like playing limbo with the bar set on top of a basketball hoop.  Style isn't the thing you really need to worry about with code quality.  Logic errors, timing bugs, race conditions, incorrect assumptions about how things work, corner cases, etc.  I'm not saying don't add it to the linter, but if you're worrying about this you're so far from producing good code its scary.  They shouldn't even be looked at in code reviews, because if you're spending your time on style issues then you're missing all the actual mistakes.

Comment: Except if you don't follow the rules about code style, there's probably other rules you won't follow in your code either. So code style rules are basically a minimum acceptance criteria. Drop that, and another standard will soon fall.

Comment: @BoboDorph The problem is that people have only so much focus (and time) they can give when reviewing.  If you're focusing on whether he forgot a space after a + in his math, you're not focusing on whether the math itself is correct.  People don't do well simultaneously focusing on minutea and the big picture.  The worst code reviews and the highest defect rate codebases I've ever seen were where people ocused in on style and not on substance of the code.  If you can fix it with a checkin autoformat, cool.  Otherwise drop it.

Comment: @BoboDorph As an example of the worst place I've ever seen-  I've been places where commits were rejected because of a lack of space after an open comment (//) operator.  That same checkin had a root vulnerability.  It went out because they weren't focusing on the big picture but the utterly unimportant stuff.